# Cant disable the microphone on a android phone

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app that only letting through microphone sound by pressing and holding the headphone pause button.

I am trying the following code to mute the microphone:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

But when this code is executed the microphone still works, can any one help me to disable the microphone? And also when the app is running in the background, it still needs to disable the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setMicMuted(boolean state){
AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// get the working mode and keep it
int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

// change mic state only if needed
if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
    myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
}

// set back the original working mode
myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to also to explain your overall solution in text, not just in comments.